# How to Display Mongoose enum in AngularJS View

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose

I've got a Mongoose schema which uses enumeration on one of its fields such as below.

```
var testSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
            type: String,
            default: '0',
            enum: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
            trim: true,
            required: 'Title cannot be blank'
        }
});
```

I would like to display the enums as options in a view with this code, but I'm unable to accomplish.

```
<datalist id="enums" data-ng-repeat="x in test.name.enumValues" >
    <option data-ng-bind="x"></option>
</datalist>
```

Is there any possible way that I can do to display these enumerations in the view? Thanks in advance.